# Trying to optimize my complex function to excute in a polynomial time

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, binary

I have this code that generate all the 2**40 possible binary numbers, and from this binary numbers, i will try to get all the vectors that match my objectif function conditions which is:
1- each vector in the matrix must have 20 of ones(1).
2- the sum of `s = s + (the index of one +1)* the rank of the one` must equal 4970.

i wrote this code but it will take a lot of time maybe months, to give the results. Now, i am looking for an alternative way or an optimization of this code if possible.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import itertools
import numpy

CC = 20
#test if there is 20 numbers of 1
def test1numebers(v,x=1,x_l=CC):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if(v[i]==x):
            c+=1
    if c == x_l:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#s = s+ the nth of 1 * (index+1)        
def objectif_function(v,x=1):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if(v[i]==x):
            s = s+((i+1)*nthi(v,i))
    return s

#calculate  the nth of 1 in a vecteur
def nthi(v,i):
    c = 0
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        if(v[j] == 1):
            c+=1
    return c

#generate 2**40 of all possible binray numbers  
def generateMatrix(N):
    l = itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=N)
    return l

#function that get the number of valide vector that match our objectif function 
def main_algo(N=40,S=4970):
    #N = 40
    m = generateMatrix(N)
    #S = 4970
    c = 0
    ii = 0
    for i in m:
        ii+=1
        print("\n count:",ii)
        xx = i
        if(test1numebers(xx)):
            if(objectif_function(xx)==S):
                c+=1
                print('found one')
                print('\n',xx,'\n')
        if ii>=1000000:
            break
    t_end = time.time()     
    print('time taken for 10**6 is: ',t_end-t_start)
    print(c)            
#main_algo()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''p = Process(target=main_algo, args=(40,4970,))
    p.start()
    p.join()'''
    p = Pool(150)
    print(p.map(main_algo, [40,4970]))
```

Comment: You should focus a lot more in readablity and use list comprehensions.
For instance
if c == x_l:
        return True
    else:
        return False
can be reduced to 
return c == x_l

if(v[j] == 1):
            c+=1
to 
if v[j]:
    c+=1

Comment: `2**40` is rather a large number, about 8 times as many as there are 40-digit numbers with 20 1s.  Modify your code to only generate those numbers.  I don't really understand your second condition, maybe that too limits the number of numbers you need to generate and test.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark do you have any idea of implementing that using Numpy ?

Comment: No, I have no idea how to use Numpy.  That's one of the reasons I'm making comments, not providing answers.  You're looking for a way to generate (only) *permutations* of the set with 20 `1`s and 20 `0`s.

Comment: Brute-force is seldom the way to go. Unless you have access to a super-computer, you are trying to do something which is infeasible. It might be a better use of time to try to improve your algorithm so that it isn't just brute-force trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

While you could make a lot of improvements in [readability](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/) and make your code more pythonic.

I recommend that you use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which is the fastest way of working with matrixes.
Avoid working with matrixes on a "pixel by pixel" loop. With numpy you can make those calculations faster and with all the data at once.
Also numpy has support for generating matrixes really fast. I think that you could make a random [0,1] matrix in less lines of code and quite faster.
Also i recommend that you install OPENBLAS, ATLAS and LAPACK which make linear algebra calculations quite faster.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i can't do it with numpy, i can do it only with iterators, with numpy i get "Minimum allowed dimension exceeded" error

Comment: Well, you can, you just don't know how. I don't understand that error.

Comment: Try this:
`import numpy as np
np.random.randint(2,size=(40,2**40))`